# Specflow read Json response

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, specflow, gherkin

Need to test GET that have Json as a response. I haven't found useful info in official documentation.

```
Feature: API_Retrieving_Platforms
    As an authorized user...
 @mytag
Scenario: Perform Get request
    Given I am an authorized user
    When I perform GET request "/api/hotels/lists/platforms",
    Then I receive a JSON in response:
    """
    [
        {
            "refId": 1,
            "label": "Mobile"
        },
        {
            "refId": 2,
            "label": "Desktop"
        }
    ]
    """
```

The step for retrieving Json is:

```
[Then(@"I receive a JSON in response:")]
    public void ThenIReceiveAJSONInResponse(string JSON)
    {
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, _responseMessage.StatusCode);
    }
```

How to parse this?
[image]

Comment: This isn't really what Gherkin was meant to be used for. Honestly I would just write these tests in C# and forget about the Gherkin language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to improve this is by not putting the exact JSON in the Specflow step.
I'd suggest using something like

```
Then I receive a response that looks like 'myResponsefile.json'
```

You could then create step which processes the response and looks at a file in your repo to compare it with

```
[Then(@"I receive a response that looks like '(.*)'")]
public void IreceiveAJsonResponse(string responsefilenametocompare)
{
        string receivedjson = GetMyReceivedjsonObject();
        string filePathAndName = "myfile.json";
        string json = File.ReadAllText(filePathAndName); 

        JToken expected = JToken.Parse(json);
        JToken actual = JToken.Parse(receivedjson);

        actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In short: [You're Cuking It Wrong](https://www.varvet.com/blog/you-re-cuking-it-wrong/).

The longer answer is that you need to write your steps differently so you remove the technical jargon from it, and focus on the business value.

```gherkin
Scenario: Retriving a list of platforms
    Given I am an authorized user
    When I retrieve a list of hotel platforms
    Then I should receive the following hotel platforms:
        | Platform |
        | Mobile   |
        | Desktop  |
```

**Step: When I retrieve a list of hotel platforms**

This step should make the GET request in C# code. Save the response of that GET request in the Scenario context.

**Step: Then I should receive the following hotel platforms:**

Makes a simple assertion, and omits technical information like the "Ref Id". The platform name is all you really care about.

A rough start to those steps would be:

```csharp
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist;

[Binding]
public class PlatformSteps
{
    private readonly ScenarioContext scenario;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the hotel platforms on the scenario context
    /// </summary>
    private IEnumerable<SomeJsonResponseType> HotelPlatforms
    {
        get => (IEnumerable<SomeJsonResponseType>)scenario["HotelPlatformsResponse"];
        set => scenario["HotelPlatformsResponse"] = value;
    }

    public PlatformSteps(ScenarioContext scenario)
    {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    [When(@"^When I retrieve a list of hotel platforms")]
    public void WhenIRetrieveAListOfHotelPlatforms()
    {
        HotelPlatforms = api.GetHotelPlatforms(); // Or whatever you API call looks like
    }

    [Then(@"^I should receive the following hotel platforms:")]
    public void IShouldReceiveTheFollowingHotelPlatforms(Table table)
    {
        var actualPlatforms = HotelPlatforms.Select(r => r.PlatformName);

        table.CompareToSet(actualPlatforms);
    }
}
```